# Hamcrest - Matchers.hasProperty: getting a weird Error : java.lang.AssertionError: No property "firstName" and No property "lastName"

Tags: java, junit5, hamcrest

> I have created one class Item and want to check if Item class property
> "firstName" is "test" and "lastName" is "best", But I am getting the
> following errors. I am not really getting what is wrong here. I have
> few doubt if following things need to be done or not.
>
> 1. Do I need to overwrite equal method for firstName and lastName.
> 2. Is there are any chances of jar conflicts
> 3. Or I am missing something
>
> Thanks in advance.

Here is my code :

```
@Test
  public void testName(){
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    Item item1= new Item("test","best");
    Item item2= new Item("test","best");
    Item item3= new Item("test","best");
    items = Arrays.asList(item1,item2,item3);
    assertThat(items,hasItems(allOf(Matchers.<Item>hasProperty("firstName",is("test")),
        Matchers.<Item>hasProperty("lastName",is("best")))));
  }
```

class Item {

```
  public Item(){}
  public Item(String firstName,String lastName){
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
  }
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
      return false;
    }

    if (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }

    final Item other = (Item) obj;
    if ((this.firstName == null) ? (other.firstName != null) : !this.firstName.equals(other.firstName)) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 53 * hash + (this.firstName != null ? this.firstName.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
  }
}
```

I am getting following Error :

```
Expected: (a collection containing (hasProperty("firstName", is "test") and hasProperty("lastName", is "best")))
     but: a collection containing (hasProperty("firstName", is "test") and hasProperty("lastName", is "best")) hasProperty("firstName", is "test") No property "firstName", hasProperty("firstName", is "test") No property "firstName", hasProperty("firstName", is "test") No property "firstName"
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: (a collection containing (hasProperty("firstName", is "test") and hasProperty("lastName", is "best")))
     but: a collection containing (hasProperty("firstName", is "test") and hasProperty("lastName", is "best")) hasProperty("firstName", is "test") No property "firstName", hasProperty("firstName", is "test") No property "firstName", hasProperty("firstName", is "test") No property "firstName"
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:8)
    at ImportTest.testName(ImportTest.java:220)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was finally able to solve the problem.  The issue is that I had
> created Item class in same class and it was not public. I created my
> Item class as a separate java class and made it public and it worked for me.

```
public class Item {

  public Item(){}
  public Item(String firstName,String lastName){
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
  }
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;


// here is the public getter and setters

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
      return false;
    }

    if (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }

    final Item other = (Item) obj;
    if ((this.firstName == null) ? (other.firstName != null) : !this.firstName.equals(other.firstName)) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 53 * hash + (this.firstName != null ? this.firstName.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
  }
}
```